# How to redeclare a function inside another function?

Tags: php, function

I have a problem creating a function which calls the parent function with parameter.

Here's my example:

```
function firstfunction($param = null){

   function secondfunction(){

       $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_id="' . fristfunciton(1) . '"');

   }

}
```

It returns an error. Please help!

Comment: You don't have this problem. There is no reason to declare a function inside of another

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Functions always exist in global scope, even if declared inside another function.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems with your code.

1. You have a typo.  In `secondfunction` you make a call to `fristfunciton` but your parent function is actually named `firstfunction`.
2. A child function within a parent function is defined when the parent function is called and both functions have the global scope.  If you call the parent function more than once (in your case, from inside the child function), it will try to define a new function with the same name.  You cannot declare 2 functions with the same name in the same scope so this fails.

More info about creating functions:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php 5.4, you could try an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

```
$first = function($param = null) {
    $second = function() {
        $query = mysql_query('...' . $first(1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
function first($arg = null) {
    if (!function_exists('second')) {
        function second() {
            first();
        }
    }
    second();
}
```

Comment: It is possible if I have to do that like this one?

function first($arg = null) {
    if (!function_exists('second')) {
        function second() {
            $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE table_id = "' . first($arg) . '"');
        }
    }
}

first('23');

Comment: Well, I am not sure to understand what you want to do, but this allows you to have a function in a function and call it recursively. Although, you are not even calling second() from first()... so what's the point? Be careful of endless loop too.